# How does writing a string using only a regex work

Tags: regex, perl

On a recreative coding website (https://dmoj.ca/user/quantum) I came across a piece of code which prints out the following string:

> If a problem can't be solved with *regex*, it's a bad problem.

I was suprised seeing the code because it seems that it only uses a regular expression to accomplish this:

```
''=~('('.'?'.'{'.('['^'+').('['^')').('`'|')').('`'|'.').('['^'/').'"'.('`'^')')
.('`'|'&').('{'^'[').('`'|'!').('{'^'[').('['^'+').('['^')').('`'|'/').('`'|'"')
.('`'|',').('`'|'%').('`'|'-').('{'^'[').('`'|'#').('`'|'!').('`'|'.')."'".('['^
'/').('{'^'[').('`'|'"').('`'|'%').('{'^'[').('['^'(').('`'|'/').('`'|',').('['^
'-').('`'|'%').('`'|'$').('{'^'[').('['^',').('`'|')').('['^'/').('`'|'(').('{'^
'[').'*'.('['^')').('`'|'%').('`'|"'").('`'|'%').('['^'#').'*'.','.('{'^'[').('`'
|')').('['^'/')."'".('['^'(').('{'^'[').('`'|'!').('{'^'[').('`'|'"').('`'|'!').
('`'|'$').('{'^'[').('['^'+').('['^')').('`'|'/').('`'|'"').('`'|',').('`'|'%').
('`'|'-').'.'.'"'.'}'.')');
```

*(all credits for this piece of art go to the original author from the website I mentioned above: Quantum)*

I really want to know how this works exactly but I couldn't find anything on Google, can someone explain this to me? Oh, and it's written in Perl.

Comment: It looks like line noise, of *course* it's written in Perl :)

Comment: It evaluates the matched result from `m/(?{print"If a problem can't be solved with *regex*, it's a bad problem."})/`

Comment: Its not a regex thing, its a _string_ thing. Perl interpolates (the string) to be `(?{print"If a problem can't be solved with *regex*, it's a bad problem."})`, which is a Perl code construct inside regex's, which prints the string you see. Code constructs are a good place to increment counters when _inline_ regex. `(?:a(?{ $coutofAs++ }))+` There are backtracking issues to consider using these constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses an Eval-group inside the regex to execute arbitrary code. You have to use `use re 'eval'` to enable the behavior.

Eval-groups look like `(?{...})` with the part inside the curly braces being evaluated.

The rest of the regex is OR'ing and XOR'ing characters. For instance `'['^'+']'` is equivalent to `'p'`. `.` simply concatenates all those characters.

You can paste the part after the `=~` matching operator into your perl shell and see the final regex that is being matched/executed.